# How to kill a subprocess after 50 seconds?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess, popen

I guess I have several questions covering multiple issues. So first, the code:

```
import subprocess
username = input ("Enter username: ")
subprocess.call(["python3", "sherlock", username])
Popen.terminate()
```

I am using `subprocess` to run the `sherlock` program using python3. The issue is, for whatever reason, the `sherlock` program does not exit when it is done. I'm not sure whether this is an issue with `sherlock`, or on my side. To be honest, I don't care, and just want to kill it on my side after giving it 50 seconds to run, as that's how long it takes to run.

I did some reading, and as far as I can tell, I should use the `Popen.terminate()` to kill it? I know the command needs more to run, I need to tell it what to kill... That's where I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to determine the running process, and then to kill it. 95% of my program occurs after sherlock runs, so it's not making it very far, so I need to just kill it and let my program continue on its way.

Not sure how to proceed from here...

UPDATE: Okay,so ive determined that the program finishes on its own, without having to kill it, but the problem is that once the program finishes, the python script does not continue. it just sits there doing nothing. is there a way to force it to move on to the next line of the script?

Comment: `terminate()` is a method of the `subprocess.Popen` instance (the subprocess) created by calling the class. However I would suggest using the `Popen.wait()` method with a `timeout` argument set to 50 seconds.

Comment: I don't know the `sherlock` program. Does it take the password as a command line argument or is it waiting for it on stdin?

Answer (score 3):

try something like this:

```
import subprocess
username = input ("Enter username: ")
try:
    ret = subprocess.call(["python3", "sherlock", username], timeout=50)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    # TODO: manage exception
    pass
```

Comment: Okay,so ive determined that the program finishes on its own, without having to kill it, but the problem is that once the program finishes, the python script does not continue. it just sits there doing nothing. is there a way to force it to move on to the next line of the script?

Comment: What do you mean the Python script doesn't continue? After the program is killed, the python instance is closed

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

> Popen.**communicate**(input=None, timeout=None)
>
> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.

I think this function is doing exactly what you want. You should pass 50 seconds to `timeout` parameter. A sample code snippet is below, again from documentation:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(...)
try:
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=50)
except TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
    outs, errs = proc.communicate()
```

Comment: Okay,so ive determined that the program finishes on its own, without having to kill it, but the problem is that once the program finishes, the python script does not continue. it just sits there doing nothing. is there a way to force it to move on to the next line of the script?

Answer (score 1):

Some processes hang waiting on data from `stdin`. In that case, close that pipe and do your own wait for termination. Some processes catch signals and may need a less subtle kick to get them to exit.

```
import subprocess
username = input ("Enter username: ")
process = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "sherlock", username],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.close()
try:
    process.wait(50)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    # timeout expired, be nice
    process.terminate()
    try:
        process.wait(2)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        # be mean
        process.kill()
        try:
            process.wait(2)
        except TimeoutExpired:
            # zombies, run!
            print("sherlock could not be killed!")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion,ive tried this, and it does not seem to be working. I dont see the sherlock could not be killed message, and sherlock is still open/preventing the rest of the process from running.I dont see any errors or anything...

Comment: Okay,so ive determined that the program finishes on its own, without having to kill it, but the problem is that once the program finishes, the python script does not continue. it just sits there doing nothing. is there a way to force it to move on to the next line of the script?

Answer (score -1):

```
import subprocess

username = input ("Enter username: ")
a_child_process = subprocess.Popen(args=["python3", "sherlock", username], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.Popen.terminate(a_child_process)
```

Comment: I guess you could add timer for the terminate command so it runs after 50 seconds if that is exactly what you really want.

Comment: Okay,so ive determined that the program finishes on its own, without having to kill it, but the problem is that once the program finishes, the python script does not continue. it just sits there doing nothing. is there a way to force it to move on to the next line of the script?